# Error on contribution details display, recently updated system

Tags: contribution-page, price-sets, debugging

Current CiviCRM is 5.6.1 running on Drupal 7.60. This system was very recently updated from 4.4.4 running on Drupal 7.36 or something. The updates were done cyclically, one right after the other, to bring it all up to date, and nothing seemed to have gone wrong.

Problem I'm having is when viewing Contact Contributions tab. The main list displays fine, but if I click on the Amount, to get an expanded details view, the expanded area *often* says `Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment`, and there is at the same time a pop-up notification bubble that says `One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer`. This does not happen for every contribution, just for many or most of them. Some of them display correctly.

I checked the Troubleshooting help page, which suggests turning on debugging including backtraces, so I did that. Sadly, nothing at all seems to have been added to the log file after reproducing errors with this setup (I don't have shell access to the server, but log files exist and I can ftp them down).

However one interesting thing did happen when I turned on debugging. Now the error message changes. The expanded space in the list is now empty, and the notification bubble says `Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again`. I tried flipping the debug setting on and off a couple times and this was replicable (i.e., with debugging off, the original message about `not of type Integer` came back).

I suppose I should mention, because you never know, that after the upgrades, I get a yellow warning in the System Status saying `the following Price Set Fields use disabled or invalid financial types and need to be fixed if they are to still be used` It refers to a field called `Contribution Amount` that has a type of `Text / Numeric Quantity`, but none of our users know what this field is, whether it is custom added here, or whether it is being actively used. It is not at all clear to me if this could be related to my main problem.

Any clues about how I can debug this are much appreciated, esp. given the situation that nothing seems to end up in the log even with full debugging traces turned on.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be worth following the lead about disabled or invalid financial types. At /civicrm/admin/financial/financialType?reset=1 , do any of the financial types show as disabled? If so, you could try enabling and seeing if that resolves the error.

If you have SQL access, you could check the financial type of working vs non-working contributions and see if there's a pattern. This is in table `civicrm_contribution`, field `financial_type_id` for the contribution itself and table `civicrm_line_item`, field `financial_type_id` for the contribution's line items.

The way price sets come into it: suppose a contribution page has a price set called Subscription, with price field Journal, with price field values (options) Print and Electronic. When you set up those price field values, you specify a financial type for each. This is stored in table `civicrm_price_field_value`, field `financial_type_id`. If the user selects "Print" and this has a financial type of "Publications", say, then the contribution will include a line item for that subscription, with financial type "Publications".

If the "Publications" financial type subsequently gets disabled or deleted, that could cause issues.

If you have SQL access, this query could shed some light on the message you  received during upgrade:

`select pfv.id, pfv.price_field_id, pfv.financial_type_id, ft.name, ft.is_active
from civicrm_price_field_value pfv
left outer join civicrm_financial_type ft on pfv.financial_type_id = ft.id
where pfv.label = 'Contribution Amount'
and pfv.is_active = 1;`

Any results where the last two columns are NULL (indicating a missing financial type) or the last column is 0 (indicating a disabled financial type) could have caused the warning you saw.

Some price sets are used behind the scenes, which could account for "Contribution Amount" not being recognised as a field that users have set up.